# How to remove extra margin from the division tag towards the top between body and div?

Tags: html, css

My div tag seems to be having a margin towards the top between the div and the body tag

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div.container {
  max-width: 920px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  display: block;
  //border: 2px dotted black;
}
```

Here are my two css for body and div, if I include the border code in the div tag then the color is blue all the way till the top otherwise there is margin of green inbetween the div and the body tag.

How do I remove this margin without using a border ?

Comment: *{margin:0px; padding:0px;} this apply for all elements in html

Comment: That did the job, but what element was causing the margin to be present because when I check via inspect it shows me 0px margin

Comment: Some browsers may have built-in styles which can make some difference in some cases. Try to search for "css normalize", and apply it before anything you define. Most of CSS frameworks use it too.

Comment: What is inside the `<div>`? Sometimes headings and paragraph tags will have margins that overflow the container. @ZoltánTamási is right though, have a look at CSS normalise to clear all the default styles before you start.

Comment: As suggested by @ZoltánTamási - Try linking to the [normalize stylesheet](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) before you apply any of your styles. It is well known and used, and I always use it in any project I do.

Comment: @AlxTheRed thanks, I did not know that some elements could have their margins overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers may have built-in styles which can make some difference in some cases. These built-in styles may include paddings, margins, other kinds of spacings, styles for `table`s, etc.

Here is a project which when included, normalizes every style which may be applied by the browser. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

As far as I know, every CSS framework use this technique too.

If that doesn't solve your issue, try to use Chrome Dev Tools or other debugging tool to check the actual DOM. The tool can provide you information about actual paddings, margins, and dimensions. For Chrome, right click your page and choose *inspect element* or something similar. You'll have a similar option in most of the modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the css normalize did not solve the problem for the margin

Comment: It's hard to tell what your exact problem can be. Try to use Chrome Dev Tools or other debugging tool to check the actual DOM. The tool can provide you information about actual paddings, margins, and dimensions. For Chrome, right click your page and choose inspect element or something similar. You'll have a similar option in most of the modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I found the <p> element to have its margin overflow. You have my vote

Comment: @JeffreyChen thanks for the feedback, I've edited my answer to include the hint about debugging tools.